# Foreach loop prints to many values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

## update, solved

I have the following 2 array's (with the same length), I want to display these values in a table. The problem is he prints just my first array ($gPositionStudents) and not the values of array $gPositionInternships.
The goal is to link each student to a different internship, but I know there is no relationship between these two array's. I'm looking for a function that can shift these 2 array's so that each time I shift the student has a other internship.

Importend to know, I did a small modification on array $gStartPositionInternship, I made this array equal in size as the length of array $gStartPositionStudents. With following code:
`enter code here`// Make items in $gStartPositionInternships as long as array $gStartPositionStudents
 $gStartPositionInternships = array_pad($internships, $lengthStudentArray, 'null');

I included my current output, see image:
[image]

```
enter code here// Make table
$header = array();
$header[] = array('data' => 'Internship');
$header[] = array('data' => 'UGentID');
// this big array will contains all rows
// global variables.
global $gStartPositionStudents;
global $gStartPositionInternships;
$rows = array();
foreach($gStartPositionStudents as $value) {
    foreach($gStartPositionInternships as $key=>$value2) {
        // each loop will add a row here.
        $row = array();
        // build the row
        $row[] = array('data' => $value[0]['value']);
        $row[] = array('data' => $value2);
    }
    // add the row to the "big row data (contains all rows)
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
}
$output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
return $output;
```

var_dump of $gPositionStudents

```
 array(148) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "804868"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "804869"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "705169"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "805148"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "702342"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "803176"
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "706651"
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "706333"
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "806026"
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      string(6) "702808"
    }
  }
```

var_dump of: $gPositionInternships

```
array(148) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "Pcv (campus Aalst)"
  [1]=>
  string(53) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Walravens Marc )"
  [2]=>
  string(54) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Peeters Stefaan )"
  [3]=>
  string(35) "psychiatrie (campus Vercruysselaan)"
  [4]=>
  string(39) "interne geneeskunde (campus Loofstraat)"
  [5]=>
  string(40) "interne geneeskunde (campus Kennedylaan)"
  [6]=>
  string(29) "heelkunde (campus Loofstraat)"
  [7]=>
  string(30) "heelkunde (campus Kennedylaan)"
  [8]=>
  string(33) "heelkunde (campus Vercruysselaan)"
  [9]=>
  string(38) "logopedie (groepspraktijk Logomatopee)"
  [10]=>
  string(41) "logopedie (Koninklijk Instituut Spermali)"
  [11]=>
  string(34) "Fysieke activiteit (To Walk Again)"
  [12]=>
  string(53) "algemene en plastische heelkunde ( AZ AZ Oudenaarde )"
  [13]=>
  string(38) "dermatologie (campus Maria Middelares)"
  [14]=>
  string(29) "NKO (campus Maria Middelares)"
  [15]=>
  string(38) "dermatologie (campus Maria Middelares)"
  [16]=>
  string(38) "Fysieke activiteit (Beweegkamp Vlabus)"
  [17]=>
  string(43) "Hoofdverpleegkundige ( UZ UZ Gent Urologie)"
  [18]=>
  string(66) "Opleidingscoördinator ( Onderwijsinstelling Arteveldehogeschool )"
  [19]=>
  string(90) "Verpleegkundig Specialist ( UMC Universitair Medisch Centrum Universitair Medisch Centrum)"
  [20]=>
  string(31) "Mss ( AZ Nikolaas campus Hamme)"
  [21]=>
  string(74) "Mss ( Privaatpraktijk kinesitherapie Cuigniez Pascale PR Cuigniez Pascale)"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same $key variables. If you don't need them, don't declare them

Comment: Yes, I know. but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: what u did with `$header` in above code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rows[] assignment is inside the nested loop - it looks suspicious to me.  Try to put that assignment after the nested loop, like this:

```
foreach($studentUGentID as $key=>$value) {
    foreach($internshipNaam as $key2=>$value2) {
    ...
    }
    // add the row to the "big row data (contains all rows)
    $rows[] = array('data' => $row);
}
```

Comment: Already did this. But, now are the values for each row of my internship the same. My ID for each student are each row different (what is good, that's what i'm expecting). But, I want for each row in my internship different values of my array. Thanks for helping anyway! (I updated the picture).

Comment: I would be simpler if you provided var_dumps of $studentUGentID and $internshipNaam.  I understand you aim to have a two column table, one row per student, first column has to be student ID, the other column should have all student's internships listed, right?

Comment: Well, it seems that there is a logic mistake. There is no relation between students and internships.  How do we know, whether a particular student participated in a particular internship or not?  The array internships should also contain some student id. That's where the problem begins, in my opinion.
I mean: it is not that each of 148 students had 106 internships, right?

Comment: Right, Ok.. my mistake. (it was a long night). I must implement the assignment problem (Genetic algorithm). It's unusfal now to get for each student ID a different internship. I must do that in my algorithm. Thanks for searching and your reply!

Comment: No problem, mate.  Once you have that relation thing fixed, the foreach problem should be easy.  If not - feel free to get back here :)

Answer (score 0):

Are your original arrays populated as expected ? Try print_f to figure it out. As far as I see if your original arrays have both 2 entries you should get a 4 entries array with like :

```
$rows = array(
    [0] => array(
        'data' => array(
            [0] => array(
                'data' => value
            ),
            [1] => array(
                'data' => value
            )
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'data' => array(
            [0] => array(
                'data' => value
            ),
            [1] => array(
                'data' => value
            )
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'data' => array(
            [0] => array(
                'data' => value
            ),
            [1] => array(
                'data' => value
            )
    ),
    [3] => array(
        'data' => array(
            [0] => array(
                'data' => value
            ),
            [1] => array(
                'data' => value
            )
        )
    )
)
```

is that really what you expect ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm expecting: ID from students are printed in first column and the name of the internship must be printed in the second column. Thanks for helping!